# Let $n \ge 2$. Prove that there is an integer divisible by $n$, whose decimal representation contains only $0$ and $5$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n \ge 2$. Prove that there is an integer divisible by $n$, whose decimal representation contains only $0$ and $5$.
Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Hint 1: Consider the numbers 5, 55, 555, 5555, ….

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @ShreevatsaR

Answer (score 3):

> Any number is a divisor of a number containing only fives and zeros.

To see this,  consider the numbers $5, 55, ... ,  c(5.....5)$, where the last one contains $n$ fives. If $n$ divides one of the above, we are done. Otherwise $n$ does not divide any of these, but since all numbers can only leave $n-1$ remainders when divided by $n$, we have that in a collection of $n$ numbers (none of which divide $n$), two numbers have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

In the above scenario, there are two such $(555....555)$ and $(555...555)$  with different number of fives, which will leave the same remainder mod $n$, so their difference is a multiple of $n$,  but the difference has only $5$ and $0$ as it's digits.

---

I'll give a method that will make the computation of this multiple easier.

EDIT : An example.

Suppose we are looking for a number having only $5$ and $0$, which is a multiple of $350$. We factorize $350 = 7 * 2 * 25$.

Now, look at the largest factor co-prime to $10$, which is $7$. The lemma above says  that there is a number which has only $5$ and $0$,  which is a multiple of $7$. You can check that $555555$ is a multiple of $7$.

Now, the remaining factors of $350$, which don't come in $555555$, are $2*25 = 50$. This has two copies of $5$ and one copy of $2$, so if I multiply $555555$ by $100 = 5*5*2*2$, then this $100$ will cancel out the $50$.

So the desired number is $55555500$.

Another example : Suppose we are looking at $48 = 3*16$. Then, the largest factors co-prime to $10$ is $3$, and we see that $555$ is a multiple of $3$ by using the lemma above. To cancel out $16= 2*2*2*2$, we multiply $10*10*10*10 = 10000$, so  the desired number is $5550000$.

You can check that $350 * 158730= 55555500$, and $48 *115625 = 5550000$, so indeed the procedures  work.

So this algorithm works faster than the conventional method above, to actually compute the multiple that has only fives and zeros.

Comment: "Any number co-prime to 10 is divisible by a number containing only fives and zeros.". Do I have to prove that? Or can I take it as an axiom? What do you mean by "remove all its factors of 2 and 5 by adding as many zeros as required (which will cancel factors of 2 and 5, resulting in a number co-prime to 10)"?

Comment: I have proved it. In the coming lines, I wrote "To see this", and then the proof after that is given. If you want, I'll give an example to clarify.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you for guiding me in refining this answer. It's something I will try to carry to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If $n = 10^k2^m$ then just multiply by $5^{m+1}$ so get $5^{m+1}10^k2^m = 5*10^{k+m}$.

If $n = 10^k5^m$ thenjust multiply by $5*2^m$ to get $5*2^mn=5*10^{k+m}$.

Otherwise $\frac 1n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}l10^{-jk}$ is a repeating infinite decimal of some period $j$ and some repeating value $l$.

$\frac 1n*(10^j - 1) = l$.

$n = \frac {10^j - 1}l$.

Example. If $n$ equals, say $17$ then $\frac 1{17} = 0.\overline{0588235294117647}$ and $\frac 1{17}(10^{16}-1) = 0588235294117647$ and $17 = \frac {10^{16}-1}{588235294117647}$.

So $ln = {10^j - 1} = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} 9*10^{i}$

$5*\frac l9*n = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} 5*10^{i}$

Example $5*\frac{588235294117647}9*17 = 5*65359477124183*17 = 5555555555555555$.

Remains to show that indeed for all $n \ne 2^p5^q$ that $\frac 1n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}l10^{-jk}$, which is something that we learned in elementary school when we learned long division, and that $9|l$.